# Git not honouring umask

Tags: git, permissions, composer-php

I have a umask set to `0002` and I have set all directories of a project with `chmod g+rws`, and the files to `chmod 664`.

Therefore, when I manually create a new directory:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ ls -ld foo
drwxrwsr-x 2 william www-data 4096 Jan 11 21:20 foo
```

and when I manually create a file:

```
$ touch foo/bar
$ ls -lh foo/bar 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 william www-data 0 Jan 11 21:21 foo/bar
```

**Both of the above are as intended** (I want others in www-data group to be able to modify them).

#### However:

Whenever I use composer install to checkout multiple git repositories, and new files and directories are created, I'm getting odd permissions:

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 william www-data 4.0K Dec 26 12:24 foo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 william www-data 3103 Dec 26 03:53 foo/bar
```

(both should be group writeable, and files are being given executable permissions they shouldn't have).

Also, `git config core.fileMode` is set to `false` on the deployment server (I gather that only covers the executable bit, not read and write).

Any suggestions what may be going on?

In this case I'm using composer to deploy WordPress - wpackagist - repositories, if the source repo is of any relevance.

(Debian Jessie, bash shell)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Git honors the umask set by the user. It's possible that something else, such as another program or the shell configuration during deployment, is set to a different value, which is causing the discrepancy.

The easiest way, however, to have Git use a particular mode for checking out files, which sounds like what you want, is to set `core.sharedRepository`, in this case to `0664`. Then Git will always write files with those permissions, regardless of the umask used to invoke it.